# Extract data from invalid JSON using bash, sed, grep or awk?

Tags: json, bash, yaml

I am trying to parse invalid JSON in bash

```
x="{componentId: 00N5E000005vm9e, componentName: Field, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 00N5E000005vm9e, componentName: Field, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 00N5E000005vm9e, componentName: Field, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 0Rb5E000000BGVi, componentName: Versions, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 0Rb5E000000BGVj, componentName: Approves, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 0Rb5E000000BGVe, componentName: activityThreads, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 0Rb5E000000BGVf, componentName: Attachments, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 0Rb5E000000BGVh, componentName: Details, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}"
```

using the following script

```
for each in $(echo $x | sed 's/{componentId: /\n/g' ); do
    echo "Each: $each"
    echo [[ $each == 0Rb* ]]
    if [[ $each == 0Rb* ]]; then
        component=echo $each | awk -v FS="(componentName: |,|referenceName: |,)" '{print $3}'
        reference=echo $each | awk -v FS="(componentName: |,|referenceName: |,)" '{print $6}'
        echo "component: $component"
        echo "reference: $component"
    fi
done
```

but it doesn't work. I don't understand why it doesn't work. When I execute this line in console,

```
echo $x | sed 's/{componentId: /\n/g'
```

I can see that this invalid json is split into lines correctly, but when I try to pass this into for-loop, each variable receives smaller chunks into it value

```
Each: 00N5E000005vm9e,
```

I am confused.

What I am trying to do is to extract the value between `componentName:`  and `,` and another value between `referenceName:`  and `,` for each item from the invalid json when `componentId` doesn't start with `00N`. Is there a way to achieve this?

I have also tried to use `jq -n $x` but it fails with `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected IDENT, expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:`

Comment: With "`for var in value`" the split is based on spaces (space, tabs, newlines...) not just newlines. Use a `while IFS= read line` loop, instead and pipe your `sed` command to it.

Comment: when I try to use `echo $x | while IFS= read -r each; do`, it takes the whole json as one each variable

Comment: Just think of it as not-json, not as an invalid json. Write a tool to parse it. `component=echo` why do you want to assign `echo` to `component`? Please check your script with shellcheck and fix mistakes. Why is it an invalid json, why isn't it valid? `do is to extract the value` To extract a value in shell, it's typicall to use regex with `awk` or `sed`. But for parsing a file in some format, write a parser in some better language, like `python` or `perl`. `jq -n $x` All your variable expansions are missing quotes. Please check your script with shellcheck.

Comment: `I am confused.` The result of unquoted command substitution `$(...)` undergoes word splitting expansion, depending on `IFS`, by default on whitespaces (tabs, newlines _and_ spaces). The result of `$(...)` is split into words on any space or newline, so `$each` becomes one word at a time. To read lines, read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 .

Comment: Maybe you could use a YAML parser, since this data is YAML and not JSON

Comment: @LéaGris could you please explain? Is there are builtin yaml parsers in bash?

Comment: @Patlatus There is `yq` to parse YAML data from a shell. Or use python yaml library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Treat the data as JSON

Convert it back to valid json with `sed`, e.g.:

```
# Remove redundant space (assuming the text is in the `x` variable)
<<<"$x" sed 's/: /:/g; s/, /,/g' |

# Quote all "words"
sed -E 's/[^"{}:,]+/"&"/g'       |

# Separate objects
sed 's/},{/}\n{/g'               |

# Parse json
jq .
```

Output:

```json
{
  "componentId": "00N5E000005vm9e",
  "componentName": "Field",
  "referenceId": "0M05E0000002XbV",
  "referenceName": "RecordPageName1",
  "referenceUrl": "null",
  "message": "Component is in use by another component in your organization.",
  "reasonCode": "10"
}
{
  "componentId": "00N5E000005vm9e",
  "componentName": "Field",
  "referenceId": "0M05E0000002XbV",
  "referenceName": "RecordPageName1",
  "referenceUrl": "null",
  "message": "Component is in use by another component in your organization.",
  "reasonCode": "10"
}
{
  "componentId": "00N5E000005vm9e",
  "componentName": "Field",
  "referenceId": "0M05E0000002XbV",
  "referenceName": "RecordPageName1",
  "referenceUrl": "null",
  "message": "Component is in use by another component in your organization.",
  "reasonCode": "10"
}
{
  "componentId": "0Rb5E000000BGVi",
  "componentName": "Versions",
  "referenceId": "0M05E0000002XbV",
  "referenceName": "RecordPageName1",
  "referenceUrl": "null",
  "message": "Component is in use by another component in your organization.",
  "reasonCode": "10"
}
{
  "componentId": "0Rb5E000000BGVj",
  "componentName": "Approves",
  "referenceId": "0M05E0000002XbV",
  "referenceName": "RecordPageName1",
  "referenceUrl": "null",
  "message": "Component is in use by another component in your organization.",
  "reasonCode": "10"
}
{
  "componentId": "0Rb5E000000BGVe",
  "componentName": "activityThreads",
  "referenceId": "0M05E0000002XbV",
  "referenceName": "RecordPageName1",
  "referenceUrl": "null",
  "message": "Component is in use by another component in your organization.",
  "reasonCode": "10"
}
{
  "componentId": "0Rb5E000000BGVf",
  "componentName": "Attachments",
  "referenceId": "0M05E0000002XbV",
  "referenceName": "RecordPageName1",
  "referenceUrl": "null",
  "message": "Component is in use by another component in your organization.",
  "reasonCode": "10"
}
{
  "componentId": "0Rb5E000000BGVh",
  "componentName": "Details",
  "referenceId": "0M05E0000002XbV",
  "referenceName": "RecordPageName1",
  "referenceUrl": "null",
  "message": "Component is in use by another component in your organization.",
  "reasonCode": "10"
}
```

To iterate over `componentId` and `referenceId` you could use the jq's `@tsv` formatting operator, e.g.:

```
... | jq -r '[ .componentId, .referenceId ] | @tsv'
```

Output:

```
00N5E000005vm9e 0M05E0000002XbV
00N5E000005vm9e 0M05E0000002XbV
00N5E000005vm9e 0M05E0000002XbV
0Rb5E000000BGVi 0M05E0000002XbV
0Rb5E000000BGVj 0M05E0000002XbV
0Rb5E000000BGVe 0M05E0000002XbV
0Rb5E000000BGVf 0M05E0000002XbV
0Rb5E000000BGVh 0M05E0000002XbV
```

### Treat the data as YAML

As noted by @léa, you can use `yq` to parse this string as a YAML array. Here
is my take on that approach using version 4.13.2 of [Mike Farah's
yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq):

```
<<<"[$x]" yq e '.[] | .componentId + " " + .referenceId' -
```

Output:

```
00N5E000005vm9e 0M05E0000002XbV
00N5E000005vm9e 0M05E0000002XbV
00N5E000005vm9e 0M05E0000002XbV
0Rb5E000000BGVi 0M05E0000002XbV
0Rb5E000000BGVj 0M05E0000002XbV
0Rb5E000000BGVe 0M05E0000002XbV
0Rb5E000000BGVf 0M05E0000002XbV
0Rb5E000000BGVh 0M05E0000002XbV
```

### Parse the variables in a bash loop

You can pipe the result from the above solutions to a `while read` loop, e.g.:

```
... | while read componentId referenceId; do 
  : Do your processing here with $componentId and $referenceId
done
```

Comment: Did you mean `echo $x | sed 's/: /:/g'`?

Comment: I mean sed 's/: /:/g' should be instead of sed 's/: //g'

Comment: @Patlatus: Yes only the space should be removed. There was a copy error, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This input string is part of a YAML objects array container. So parse it with a YAML parser.

With Python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import yaml
import json

# Your input invalid JSON but valid YAML elements part of an array
x = "{componentId: 00N5E000005vm9e, componentName: Field, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 00N5E000005vm9e, componentName: Field, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 00N5E000005vm9e, componentName: Field, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 0Rb5E000000BGVi, componentName: Versions, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 0Rb5E000000BGVj, componentName: Approves, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 0Rb5E000000BGVe, componentName: activityThreads, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 0Rb5E000000BGVf, componentName: Attachments, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 0Rb5E000000BGVh, componentName: Details, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}"

# Compose yamlstring from x by adding the missing data array container
yamlstring = "data: [" + x + "]"

# Load data from the yamlstring
data = yaml.load(yamlstring, yaml.SafeLoader)

# Output data as JSON
json.dump(data, sys.stdout, indent=2)
```

Or from a shell using `yq` as parser:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

x="{componentId: 00N5E000005vm9e, componentName: Field, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 00N5E000005vm9e, componentName: Field, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 00N5E000005vm9e, componentName: Field, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 0Rb5E000000BGVi, componentName: Versions, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 0Rb5E000000BGVj, componentName: Approves, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 0Rb5E000000BGVe, componentName: activityThreads, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 0Rb5E000000BGVf, componentName: Attachments, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}, {componentId: 0Rb5E000000BGVh, componentName: Details, referenceId: 0M05E0000002XbV, referenceName: RecordPageName1, referenceUrl: null, message: Component is in use by another component in your organization., reasonCode: 10}"

yamlstring="data: [$x]"

printf %s "$yamlstring" | yq -I 4 -o json e '.' -
```

Comment: isn't yq part of bash distribution? Do I have to install it? How do I install yq?

Comment: @Patlatus `yq` is not part of Bash distribution. It has to be installed. You are more likely to have `python3` with `yaml` and `json` libraries already available than having `yq` whose distribution is much less integrated, often require `snap` or docker images. Also python is a much more appropriate scripting language than shell to deal with any of these structured data.

Comment: sounds like an interesting approach, however, I just want to have some simple script without python and yq is hard to install

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments, looks like I have figured this out.

```
echo $x | sed 's/{componentId: /\n/g' | while IFS=\n read -r each; do
    #echo "Each: $each"
    #echo [[ $each == 0Rb* ]]
    if [[ $each == 0Rb* ]]; then
        component=$(echo $each | awk -v FS="(componentName: |,|referenceName: |,)" '{print $3}')
        reference=$(echo $each | awk -v FS="(componentName: |,|referenceName: |,)" '{print $6}')
        echo "component: $component"
        echo "reference: $reference"
    fi
done
```